# Error with connectin to database using sqlite3 with python

Tags: sqlite, python-3.5

When running following code I get error which I posted at the bottom of the post. I followed tutorial on creating databases from [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/create-tables/).
These functions worked when creating previous databases though.

I am using jupyter notebook v 3.5.

```
def create_connection(db_file):

  try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    return conn
  except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print("Connection error: [%s]" % e)

  return None

def create_table(conn, create_table_sql ):

  try:
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(create_table_sql)
  except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print("Connection error while creating table: [%s]" % e)

def sqlTables(db_file):

  sql_create_synset_table = ''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_data (

                                    id TEXT NOT NULL,
                                    status TEXT NOT NULL,
                                    confidence_score INT NOT NULL,
                                                ); '''
  conn = create_connection(db_file)
  if conn is not None:
    create_table(conn,sql_create_synset_table)
  else:
    print("Error! cannot create db conn.")

def upload_data(db_file):
 sqlTables(db_file)
 conn = create_connection(db_file)
 cursor = conn.cursor()

 with conn:
    for i in range(len(id_list)):
        s_id = id_list[i]
        status = status_list[i]
        conf = conf_list[i]  

        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_data(id, status, confidence_score) VALUES(?,?,?)"\
                                                    ,(s_id, status, conf))
        conn.commit()

upload_data("path/to/db/table.db")
```

> Connection error while creating table: [near ")": syntax error]
>
> ---> 12             cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_data(id, status, confidence_score) VALUES(?,?,?)"                                                        ,(sset_id, stus, conf))
>
> OperationalError: no such table: table_data

Comment: Pay attention to the commas in your CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: @Sha Yes, that was the case. Thank you. Add an answer if you want accepted answer.